# Will a naked domain that isn't setup hurt PageRank?

Tags: seo, pagerank

Say we have a domain, `example.com`, and I just want the site to be viewed under `www.example.com`.

I know that the best practice would be to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`.  However, if this isn't an option and the naked domain is left un-configured, will this harm my PageRank?

Comment: Not if you use canonical tags to point to the preferred site. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en Still, there may be other options to redirect one to another such as using PHP.

Comment: "isn't setup" - literally does not return anything? Or you've simply not implemented the canonical redirect (but otherwise returns the same content)?

Comment: Sorry, could have been clearer.  "Isn't setup" meaning that nothing is returned at all.  In other words, no duplicate content issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not make a significant difference as long as the domain remains unconfigured and doesn't show any duplicate content - for example a copy of the main website as that would be considered a bad practice.